# jq command prints the json twice instead of only once

Tags: json, set, jq

I need to set some new value using jq command in a JSON file.
Here is an example of file.json

```
{
  
  "Balise1": true,
  "Balise2": true,
  "OtherThingEnabled": false,
  "proxySettings": {
    "port": 0
  },
  "mailSettings": {},
  "maxRunningActivitiesPerJob": 5,
  "maxRunningActivities": 5,
}
```

In order to set the proxySettings value I use the following command

`jq --arg host "proxy.hub.gcp.url.com" --arg port "80" '.proxySettings = { host: $host, port: $port }' file.json`

Instead of printing the modified version of file.json, it prints both original and modified version like that:

```
{
  
  "Balise1": true,
  "Balise2": true,
  "OtherThingEnabled": false,
  "proxySettings": {
    "port": 0
  },
  "mailSettings": {},
  "maxRunningActivitiesPerJob": 5,
  "maxRunningActivities": 5,
}
{
  
  "Balise1": true,
  "Balise2": true,
  "OtherThingEnabled": false,
  "proxySettings": {
    "host": "proxy.hub.gcp.url.com"
    "port": "80"
  },
  "mailSettings": {},
  "maxRunningActivitiesPerJob": 5,
  "maxRunningActivities": 5,
}
```

I was expecting to print only the modified version.
How could I create a new JSON file only with the modified version?

Comment: It only prints out one JSON blob for me (the second from your example).  Are you sure you are showing us the right code and data?  Also note that your example blob isn't valid JSON, because of the trailing comma after the final value.

Comment: I cannot reproduce. Please double-check your input file.

Answer (score 1):

[Comma `,`](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#Comma:,) feeds the same input to two filters, therefore programs such `., .` will output their input twice.

> If two filters are separated by a comma, then the same input will be fed into both and the two filters' output value streams will be concatenated in order: first, all of the outputs produced by the left expression, and then all of the outputs produced by the right. For instance, filter .foo, .bar, produces both the "foo" fields and "bar" fields as separate outputs.

Demo:

```
echo '"foobar"' | jq 'length, length'
6
6
```

Instead, you want to combine both filters sequentially with the [pipe filter `|`](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#Pipe:%7C), since the [plain assignment operator `=`](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#Plainassignment:=) outputs its modified input.

```
jq --arg host "proxy.hub.gcp.url.com" \
   --arg port "80" \
   '.proxySettings = { host: $host, port: $port } | .mailSettings = {value1: "Value1"}'
```

Your initial question didn't include the full jq program (so it was missing a proper [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)!), only your self-answer included the crucial details.

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue.
I my shell I was modifying 2 thing on the same command like this :

```
jq --arg host "proxy.hub.gcp.url.com" --arg port "80" '.proxySettings = { host: $host, port: $port }, .mailSettings = '{value1: "Value1"}' file.json
```

The command was printing the first change, then the second one. I had to create two seperate jq command.

Comment: Please include the full [mre] in your question. You have to use the `pipe` filter/operator, see [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74994935/112968)